# Why is the bullet going the wrong way?

Tags: javascript, formula

I'm trying to make a shooter game and the bullets are going the wrong way.

I've tried to mess a little bit with the formulas but I have no clue on how to solve this issue.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".bullet").each(function(i,bullet) {
        var x = parseFloat($(bullet).css("left")) + parseFloat($(bullet).attr("y"));
        var y = parseFloat($(bullet).css("top")) + parseFloat($(bullet).attr("x"));

        $(bullet).css({"top":y+"px","left":x+"px"});
    });
},20);
```

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    var dx = (e.pageX - (x+37.5));
    var dy = (e.pageY - (y+37.5));
    var mag = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    var velX = (dx / mag) * 15;
    var velY = (dy / mag) * 15;

    $("#game").append("<div class=\"bullet\" x=\""+velX+"\" y=\""+velY+"\" age=\"0\" style=\"top:"+(parseFloat($("#user").css("top"))+37.5)+"px;left:"+(parseFloat($("#user").css("left"))+37.5)+"px;\"></div>");
});
```

[Here's a GIF of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlSBl.gif)

Comment: please share html as well

Comment: `I'm trying to make a shooter game and the bullets are going the wrong way.` Can you please explain what the `right` way is first? There's no way this question can be answered with this information.

Comment: You're adding "left" with "y" and "top" with "x". That doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding X to Y and Y to X is one observation:

```
var x = parseFloat($(bullet).css("left")) + parseFloat($(bullet).attr("x"));
var y = parseFloat($(bullet).css("top")) + parseFloat($(bullet).attr("y"));
```

**instead of**

```
var x = parseFloat($(bullet).css("left")) + parseFloat($(bullet).attr("y"));
var y = parseFloat($(bullet).css("top")) + parseFloat($(bullet).attr("x"));
```